# java Hibernate annotation to allow text box 'blank' on submitting a form

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, annotations

In a form, I have a number of text boxes.

I want to have one of the text boxes as optional.
That is the user may or maynot fill this text box.
The user can leave it empty during submission.
But if the user enters any value, that must be an url.

I am using the following code.

```
@URL
@Size(max = 100)
public String getLastName() {
     return lastName;
    }
```

This is working fine when the user enters any url (http://*/*) But if I leave the text box emoty, I am getting error. Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Comment: how about @Size(min = 0, max = 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two things:
1. Allow null in the database table design for the relative field and do something like (if the desired variable is last name)

```
String lastName=null;

public String getLastName() {
 return lastName;
}
```

2. check the value of last name in the *getLastName* method and pass some any specific string if the value is not set.

```
public String getLastName() {
  if(lastName==null)
  {
     return "null"; // or " "
  }

  return lastName;
}
```

but you need to check these value again when reading from database.